# ksh - passing parameter with space

Tags: parameters, ksh, spacing

am trying to pass a parameter with a space in ksh via variables.

Here is some sample code to demonstrate the issue. As you will see the parameter with the space is later handled as two variables - not what I am after.

*Update - I didn't copy and paste all the code in the origianl question. **

Contents of param_test.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh

echo "check 1"

param_string=${1}
param_string2=${2}

echo "check 2"

echo param_string = $param_string
echo param_string2 = $param_string2

echo "check 3"
```

Contents of call_param_test.sh

```
#!/bin/ksh

param_test.sh 'a b' c

CMD="param_test.sh 'a b' c"

# CMD=param_test.sh
# CMD="${CMD} 'a b c'"


echo CMD is  $CMD

echo now running CMD
${CMD}

echo back to calling script

echo at end


Results of executing call_param_test.sh

check 1
check 2
param_string = a b
param_string2 = c
check 3
CMD is param_test.sh 'a b' c
now running CMD
check 1
check 2
param_string = 'a
param_string2 = b'
check 3
back to calling script
at end
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) is applicable. In general you should try to avoid putting commands in variables. If you must do it then an array is probably the way to go:

```
# create an array
CMD=(param_test.sh 'a b' c)
# execute the command contained in the array
${CMD[@]}
```

Comment: Thank Dennis, the secret sauce I needed was $( ).
What has seemed to work for me is to use this -
    myvar='\test\test'
    out=$(print -R $myvar |sed 's/\\/\\\\\\/g')

Answer (score 0):

I changed the calling script something like this

```
#param_test.sh 'a b' c

#CMD="./param_test.sh \'a b\' c"
CMD="./param_test.sh"
ARGS1="a b"
ARGS2=c

# CMD=param_test.sh
# CMD="${CMD} 'a b c'"


echo CMD is  $CMD  $ARGS

echo now running CMD
#${CMD}
#${CMD} "$ARGS1" ${ARGS2}

echo back to calling script

echo at end
```

Since the args have spaces its quite tricky to give its as argument(I hope there shuld be better way).
But the above works even though not an effective approach

Comment: Hi Raghuram,  thanks for the answere but I have updated the original post. Hopefully that will explain what I am trying to get at better.